# Tridion.ContentManager.Data FileNotFoundException

Tags: core-service, 2013

I have a small core service app which is experiencing a `FileNotFoundException` for `Tridion.ContentManager.Data.dll` at runtime. I can't locate this .dll in the usual spots (e.g [Tridion]\bin\client), nor is it contained inside of `Tridion.ContentManager.dll`. I'm using exclusively Tridion 2013 .dlls, targeting X64 and .NET 4.0.

I'm frankly a bit stumped because this seems like a simple problem, and an unusual one since I've used core service apps before and not had this come up. I must be missing something obvious, but I'm not sure where to turn for debugging purposes.

Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Please include stack trace also see if there is any additional info in the client event log and/or server. Also please mention if you are using the provided `CoreServiceClient`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That DLL is not public, you can find it in the GAC `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Tridion.ContentManager.Data\v4.0_7.0.0.2303__ddfc895746e5ee6b`. Please review your app references/code since it shouldn't reference/use that DLL directly

Comment: This was indeed where I found it (not present on my dev machine, which is why the error was being thrown) but I am curious as to why my code was searching for it in the first place. I definitely didn't directly reference it, as it compiled fine. What does the .dll do? How does it interact with the core service client?

Comment: It is part of the CMS DA Layer, in the server side the core services call it but it is hidden from the client side. Probably you are not using it but you are referencing it somewhere. Is your application referencing other dll than the core services one?

Comment: Tridion.Common, Tridion.ContentManager, and Tridion.ContentManager.Common are explicitly referenced.

Comment: That is indeed the reason behind the error, try to don't use those DLLs in the client side, is there any specific functionality why you are using those DLLs?, perhaps the TCMUri class isn't it?

Comment: It is indeed the TCMUri class, which I use in the constructor for a Publication object. What .dlls should be used for this purpose if not Common and ContentManager?

Comment: I think you are mixing coding concepts here, if you are using CoreServices you should retrieve a Publication using the CoreService.Read(Id, ReadOptions) method which will return a PublicationData object, you don't need to create a Publication object.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. Thanks! I'll refactor this code.